# SDL2 window and fullscreen-window each on its own screen

Tags: macos, window, focus, sdl-2, multiple-monitors

I use macOS 10.12 with two screens. Now I want to create two windows with SDL2.0.5. One window (400x400pixel) on the one screen/monitor and the other window as a fullscreen-window on the second screen/monitor. This works well so far, but if I click/focus on the first window(400x400), the second window/screen fades to black and stays black as long the application is running.

Note: `SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_VIDEO_MINIMIZE_ON_FOCUS_LOSS, "0");` does not help.

Is it possible to create such windows as described?

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible, but it might be a Mac-specific bug. I'll check this today, but if you don't hear back, please feel free to file a bug at https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/ about it!

Thanks,
--ryan.

Comment: I've just tested this on an Ubuntu-machine. It's also *not* working. A work-around could be calling `SDL_SetWindowFullscreen` with `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP`